# How to avoid redeclaring dependencies in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

How to avoid redeclaring dependencies in gradle. **com.foo.sso.keycloak** was built using **org.keycloak.keycloak-admin-client** and I don't want to redeclare the dependency even if I use packages from **keycloak-admin-client**. How do I enable this?

MyApplication's build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-boot-starter', version: '15.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '15.0.0'
implementation group: 'com.foo.sso.keycloak', name: 'sso-keycloak-admin', version: '15.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `api` when defining the dependencies in build.gradle of `keycloak-admin-client`. This will expose them to the projects that in turn depend on the client.

Ex:

```
// build.gradle (keycloak-admin-client)
api group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-boot-starter', version: '15.0.0'
```

```
// build.gradle (com.foo.sso.keycloak)
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '15.0.0'
implementation group: 'com.foo.sso.keycloak', name: 'sso-keycloak-admin', version: '15.0.0'
```